# What is the difference between weka CostSensitiveClassifier and weka MetaCost?

Tags: weka

I have read that weka MetaCost's implementation refer to the implementation explained in Pedro Domingo's paper (1999). But I didn't find any explanation of weka CostSensitiveClassifier implementation.

I just found that, with CostSensitiveClassifier, the user can choose between applying the cost to training set (reweighting examples)  or to predict labels in test set. It is a poor description...